# If $f > 0$ a.e. on $E$ and $m(E) > 0$ then $\int_E f \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Where $E$ is a measurable set.

Say I define a set $H = \{x \in E : \int_Ef = 0\}$. Then $H \subseteq E$ and $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $H$. However, $f > 0$ almost everywhere on $E$. Therefore $m(H) = 0$.

Therefore, we have that $m(E-H) = m(E) > 0$, where $E-H$ is the set where the integral is nonzero. So

$$\int_Ef = \int_{E-H} f \neq 0$$

Is this correct? Is there a clearer way to do it?

Comment: The way you've defined $H$, it is empty.  The conditions don't depend on $x$ (and are always false).  If you change the condition to $f(x)=0$, then you'll get what you're looking for, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear. $H$ has no sense.

Let $F_n=\{x\mid f\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. In particular, $$F=\bigcup_{n}F_n=\{x\mid f(x)>0\},$$
and thus $m(F_n)>0$ for a certain $n$ (why ?). Now, $$f\geq f\chi_{F_n}\geq \chi_{F_n}\frac{1}{n}\implies \int f\geq \frac{1}{n}m(F_n)>0$$
what prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the following, as it is not clear that $H$ is measurable:

Let $A_n = \{ x \in E \mid f(x) > \frac{1}{n} \} = f^{-1} ( ( \frac{1}{n} , \infty ))$ which is measurable as $f$ and $(\frac{1}{n} , \infty )$ are measurable.
Then we have $f_n(x) = f(x)\mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x) \uparrow f(x)$ for all $x \in E$, so by MCT we have 
$$\int f \textrm{d} \mu= \int \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \textrm{d} \mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \textrm{d} \mu.$$
Thus we have $\int f \textrm{d} \mu= 0$ iff $\int f_n \textrm{d} \mu= 0$ for every $n$.
We have $f_n \ge 0$, and so $\int f_n\textrm{d} \mu = 0$ iff $f_n = 0$ a.e.. But we also have 
$$\mu (E) = \mu \left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right) + \mu \left( f^{-1}(0) \right) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (A_n)$$
So there exists at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu (A_n ) >0$, and then we have
$$ \int f_n \textrm{d} \mu \ge \int \frac{1}{n} \textrm{d} \mu = \frac{\mu (A_n) }{n} > 0.$$
Thus we have $\int f \textrm{d} \mu >0$.